# Detecting when pppoe succesfully connect

Tags: networking, server, pppoe

I have setup ddclient in order to autoupdate my DDNS public IP every time my connection to the pppoe interface goes up. I noticed that ddclient (that is *not* setup as a daemon) is run just when the ppp connection is stablished, so the IP is then updated accordingly.

Question is, how can I setup any script at this point (when the IP get refreshed) in order to update a few things (iptables rules, and so on)

using ubuntu server zesty - 17.04

Thanks in advance

Comment: I answer myself. pppoe package is setup in /etc/ppp. There is a sub directory there ip-up.d where many scripts are located (even the one from ddclient) that are run with a few global parameters that can be used to setup things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained above, the solution is to place the script in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d and it will be run when the link is stablished.